# Moving Files with SSIS package, scheduled by a SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent

I developed quite a complex SSIS package. Part of it Moves Files from the "c:\Flags\" folder to the "c:\Flags\Busy\" folder.

I deploy the package under the SSIS Catalog.

When i right click and start the task manually, under my own credentials,  it works fine. (i am administrator)

When i schedule the task (to run say every 30 mins) using the SQL Server Agent, it it fails in the part where the files gets moved. The SSIS Package runs under the "SQL SERVER AGENT ACCOUNT", by default.

Any suggestions or pointers how i can resolve the issue? (i did google the issue)

Maybe change the account it runs under (no options here from the GUI) or somehow give the "SQL SERVER AGENT ACCOUNT" rights to move files?

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting when running the package through the job?

Comment: It's almost certainly file system permissions for the SQL Agent account.  Did you include how to do that in your googling?

Comment: what attempts you made to solve the issue?

Comment: using "services.msc" find under whose credential sql sever is running  give that user  full access on path...

Comment: In the past where I had to move files with an SSIS package, it applied a Proxy with credentials applying a unique static (password does not need to be updated very x number of days) network account that had the necessary permissions on one or more servers to apply a file move/copy task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agent account will almost always have insufficient rights to this type of task depending on where exactly the files are located.  You could give more rights to the account but this is not recommended.  I suggest a proxy.

http://sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-dba-tip-credentials-and-proxies

Answer (score 0):

I added the "NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT" to my folder where I move the files, and granted Modify rights. This resolved the issue for me. Kind Regards.